# Alert Box error

Tags: javascript, alert

I have alert boxes all around my site, that have been working up until now, ( I have done a few updates to my blog recently before this started happening ) the problem I am experienceing is that when I click on a link ( in my case a image link ) and the alert box appears, I submitt the ok button and suddenly im rediercted to a white page with 'true' in the top corner. My alert box scripts are inside my blog template.

I tested this alert box script out in a blog post:

```
<"a href="javascript:onClick=alert(&quot;Not an active link&quot;);">CLICK<"/a>
```

*withouth the extra "*

and then went to preview the post, however the same error occured. This is not a browser problem as it only happens on my site, when i got to someone elses with alert boxes, it works. Please help with this I have been asking about it for about a week now and would appreciate someone who can help

here is a screenshot of what I get redirected to:

[image: true]
http://img813.imageshack.us/img813/2674/true.png

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you messed up with javascript inside href and the onclick attribute. Your snippet is actually assigning the result of the `alert` function call to the variable `onCLick`. The display of true might be the return value of the `alert` method. Still an odd behavior.

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Not an active link');">CLICK</a>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Not an active link');">CLICK</a>
```

Those two cause no problems to me.

Comment: Thankyou very much :D <a href="#" onclick="javascript:alert('Not an active link');">CLICK</a> works perfectyl

Comment: Keep in mind that the hash-sign (#) makes the browser jump to the very top of the page.

Comment: The "javascript:" part in the onclick event is unnecessary

onclick="alert('Not an active link');"

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<a href="javascript:onClick=alert('Not an active link');">CLICK</a>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/e2fkT/embedded/result/

Comment: it still redirects me to white page with 'true' in corner when i click ok on the alert box

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some typos... It would be:

```
<a href="javascript:onclick=alert('Not an active link');">click</a>
```

Use simple quotes inside or escape double quotes.

I don't understand the use of onclick there too... Just the alert will open an alert box when you click.

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Not an active link');">click</a>
```

Also it would be better to separate javascript from html... You could include with the following content (jquery example, i forgot almost everything about old javascript... just get the idea) into a non-active-links.js file or in a  block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.non-active-link').click(function () {
        window.alert('Not an active link');
        return false;
    });
});
```

That way all links in the page with a class attribute of "non-active-link" will fire up the alert box.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this is a great answer, and that we need more people like you on this site – thanks!